# Order string column is not working properly

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sorting

I have a database named **sang.mdf** and ascending on a serial number column is not working properly in  C# Windows Forms.

I tried:

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select slno, date, name, total from printi ORDER BY slno ASC", con);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
sda.Fill(ds);
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
con.Close();
```

With this code the sorted elements look like this:

```
slno   date     name     total

1    
10  
11  
12  
13  
2  
20  
21  
3  
4    
5
```

Comment: not working properly? how is it behaving?  Is the column varchar type? it is expected if datatype is varchar

Comment: The order of serial number is 1, 10,11,12,13,14,2,20,21,22,3,4,5

Comment: SELECT *, CAST(yourColumn AS int) AS yourColumnInt
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY yourColumnInt
Give this a try

Comment: The coloum slno is in varchar format. I changed It to Int. So The Sorting Works... Thanks

Comment: You can also try
select
  col1, col2, ...
from
  yourTable
order by
  case when isnumeric(Field1) = 1 then cast(col1 as int) else null end

Yes slno is varchar format and hence you have to cast it to INT to perform sorting ( sorting as an integer )

Comment: Ok. if you have feasibility to change your column type, well and good. Or else you can give a try to the mention options to achieve what you want

Comment: My another problem is that. When i press "A" in textbox1 then i want to show "Apple", "Animals", "Aloy", as suggestions. can you help me how to do that?

Comment: you have to set AutoCompleteSource for your textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [cast](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_cast.asp) your column value to an int. Like this:

```
cast(slno as int)
```

And in C#:

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select slno, date, name, total " +
                                        "from printi ORDER BY cast(slno as int) ASC", con);
```